# C++ threaded task manager

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I've been writing a little task manager in C++ in my spare time. It's also the first time I am posting here for a review, I hope someone can spot any mistakes.
There's still a lot to implement and optimise, but the idea is for this to be a task manager that optionally uses any platform-dependent threading API (otherwise can default to std::thread).

It works like this:

- Spawn N workers (where N is the specified concurrency)
- Each worker pulls jobs from its own local queue
- When the worker has no job available, it tries to steal from a random queue
- Job dependencies work by resolving any child jobs first by waiting on the jobCount to be 1 (example #2, below)

It's currently tested on Windows and Linux. What I'd like is to move to a lock-free queue at some point, as there seems to be a lot of contention with the current mechanism of job stealing.

Apologising in advance for the long post.

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <random>

#ifndef YATM_ENABLE_WORK_STEALING
    #define YATM_ENABLE_WORK_STEALING (1u)
#endif // YATM_ENABLE_WORK_STEALING

#ifndef YATM_CACHE_LINE_SIZE
    #define YATM_CACHE_LINE_SIZE (64u)
#endif // YATM_CACHE_SIZE

#ifndef YATM_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE
    #define YATM_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE (1024u * 1024u)
#endif // YATM_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE

#ifndef YATM_DEFAULT_JOB_SCRATCH_BUFFER_SIZE
    #define YATM_DEFAULT_JOB_SCRATCH_BUFFER_SIZE (128u * 1024u)
#endif // YATM_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE

#ifndef YATM_MAX_WORKER_MASK_STACK_DEPTH
    #define YATM_MAX_WORKER_MASK_STACK_DEPTH (64u)
#endif // YATM_MAX_WORKER_MASK_STACK_DEPTH

#ifndef YATM_ASSERT
    #define YATM_ASSERT(x) assert((x))
#endif // YATM_ASSERT

#ifndef YATM_TTY
    #define YATM_TTY(x) std::cout << (x) << std::endl
#endif // YATM_TTY

#ifndef YATM_DEBUG
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        #define YATM_DEBUG (_DEBUG)
    #endif //_MSC_VER
#endif // YATM_DEBUG

// When STD_THREAD is defined, undef platform_specific.
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
#undef YATM_WIN64
#undef YATM_LINUX
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD

#if YATM_WIN64
    #define NOMINMAX
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <Windows.h>
#elif YATM_LINUX
    #include <unistd.h>
#elif YATM_STD_THREAD
    #include <thread>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <atomic>
    #include <chrono>
#endif // YATM_WIN64

#define YATM_USE_PTHREADS (YATM_LINUX)

#if YATM_USE_PTHREADS
    #include <pthread.h>
#endif // YATM_USE_PTHREADS

// Some defaults for reserving space in the job queues

#ifndef YATM_DEFAULT_JOB_QUEUE_RESERVATION
    #define YATM_DEFAULT_JOB_QUEUE_RESERVATION (1024u)
#endif // YATM_DEFAULT_JOB_QUEUE_RESERVATION

#ifndef YATM_DEFAULT_PENDING_JOB_QUEUE_RESERVATION
    #define YATM_DEFAULT_PENDING_JOB_QUEUE_RESERVATION (128u)
#endif // YATM_DEFAULT_PENDING_JOB_QUEUE_RESERVATION

namespace yatm
{
    static_assert(sizeof(void*) == 8, "Only 64bit platforms are currently supported");

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // std::bind wrapped, used specifically for the job callbacks.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    template<typename Fx, typename... Args>
    static auto bind(Fx&& _function, Args&&... _args)
    {
        return std::bind(std::forward<Fx>(_function), std::forward<Args>(_args)..., std::placeholders::_1);
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Align input to the next specified alignment.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    static size_t align(size_t _value, size_t _align)
    {
        return (_value + (_align - 1)) & ~(_align - 1);
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Align pointer to the next specified alignment.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    static uint8_t* align_ptr(uint8_t* _ptr, size_t _align)
    {
        return (uint8_t*)align((size_t)_ptr, _align);
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // A representation of an OS mutex.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class mutex
    {
        friend class condition_var;
    public:
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        mutex()
        {
#if YATM_WIN64
            InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_mutex_init(&m_pmtx, nullptr);
#endif // YATM_WIN64
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
        mutex operator=(const mutex&) = delete;

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ~mutex()
        {

#if YATM_WIN64
            DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_pmtx);
#endif // YATM_WIN64
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Lock the mutex, claiming ownership.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void lock()
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            m_mutex.lock();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            int32_t const errorCode = pthread_mutex_lock(&m_pmtx);
            YATM_ASSERT(errorCode == 0);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Try to lock the mutex, returning true if it did.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        bool try_lock()
        {
            bool v = false;
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            v = m_mutex.try_lock();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            v = TryEnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            v = (pthread_mutex_trylock(&m_pmtx) == 0);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD

            return v;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Unlock the mutex, giving-up ownership.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void unlock()
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            m_mutex.unlock();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            int32_t const errorCode = pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_pmtx);
            YATM_ASSERT(errorCode == 0);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

    private:
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
        std::mutex m_mutex;
#elif YATM_WIN64
        CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
        pthread_mutex_t m_pmtx;
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
    };

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // A scoped-lock mechanism for mutexes.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    template<typename T>
    class scoped_lock
    {
        friend class condition_var;
    public:
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        scoped_lock(T* _mutex) : m_mutex(_mutex), m_locked(false)
        {
            lock();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ~scoped_lock()
        {
            unlock();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        scoped_lock(const scoped_lock&) = delete;
        scoped_lock& operator=(const scoped_lock&) = delete;

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void lock()
        {
            if (!m_locked)
            {
                m_mutex->lock();
            }
            m_locked = true;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void unlock()
        {
            if (m_locked)
            {
                m_mutex->unlock();
            }
            m_locked = false;
        }

    private:
        bool m_locked;
        T* m_mutex;
    };

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // A representation of an OS condition variable.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class condition_var
    {
    public:
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        condition_var()
        {
#if YATM_WIN64
            InitializeConditionVariable(&m_cv);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_cond_init(&m_cv, nullptr);
#endif // YATM_WIN64
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ~condition_var()
        {
#if YATM_WIN64

#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_cond_destroy(&m_cv);
#endif // YATM_WIN64
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        condition_var(const condition_var&) = delete;
        condition_var& operator=(const condition_var&) = delete;

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Notify all threads waiting on this condition variable.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void notify_all()
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            m_cv.notify_all();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            WakeAllConditionVariable(&m_cv);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&m_cv);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Notify a thread waiting on this condition variable.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void notify_one()
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            m_cv.notify_one();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            WakeConditionVariable(&m_cv);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_cond_signal(&m_cv);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Wait on this condition variable.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        template<typename Condition>
        void wait(mutex& _lock, const Condition& _condition)
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            m_cv.wait(_lock, _condition);
#elif YATM_WIN64
            while (!_condition())
            {
                SleepConditionVariableCS(&m_cv, &_lock.m_cs, INFINITE);
            }
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            while (!_condition())
            {
                    pthread_cond_wait(&m_cv, &_lock.m_pmtx);
            }
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

    private:
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
        std::condition_variable_any m_cv;
#elif YATM_WIN64
        CONDITION_VARIABLE m_cv;
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
        pthread_cond_t m_cv;
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
    };

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // An atomic counter used for synchronisation.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class counter
    {
    public:
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        counter() : m_value(0u) { }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        counter(const counter&) = delete;
        counter& operator=(const counter&) = delete;

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Checks if the internal atomic counter has reached 0.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        bool is_done()
        {
            uint32_t expected = 0u;
#if YATM_STD_THREAD || YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            return m_value.compare_exchange_weak(expected, get_current());
#elif YATM_WIN64
            return get_current() == expected;
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Checks the internal atomic counter for quality.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        bool is_equal(uint32_t _value)
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD || YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            return m_value.compare_exchange_weak(_value, get_current());
#elif YATM_WIN64
            return get_current() == _value;
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Increment the internal atomic counter and return its value.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        uint32_t increment()
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(get_current() < UINT_MAX);
#if YATM_STD_THREAD || YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            return ++m_value;
#elif YATM_WIN64
            return InterlockedIncrement(&m_value);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Decrement the internal atomic counter and return its value.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        uint32_t decrement()
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(get_current() != 0);
#if YATM_STD_THREAD || YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            return --m_value;
#elif YATM_WIN64
            return InterlockedDecrement(&m_value);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Returns the current value of the internal atomic counter.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        uint32_t get_current()
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD || YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            return m_value.load();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            return InterlockedCompareExchange(&m_value, 0, 0);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

    private:
#if YATM_STD_THREAD || YATM_USE_PTHREADS
        std::atomic_uint32_t m_value;
#elif YATM_WIN64
        LONG m_value;
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
    };

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Describes a job that the scheduler can run.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    struct alignas(YATM_CACHE_LINE_SIZE) job
    {
        using JobFuncPtr = std::function<void(void* const)>;

        JobFuncPtr  m_function;
        void*       m_data;
        counter*    m_counter;
        job*        m_parent;
        uint32_t    m_workerMask;
        counter     m_pendingJobs;
    };

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // A representation of an OS thread.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class thread
    {
        typedef void(*ThreadEntryPoint)(void*);
    public:
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        thread()
            :
            m_stackSizeInBytes(0),
            m_index(0)
#if YATM_WIN64
            , m_handle(nullptr)
#endif // YATM_WIN64
        {

        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ~thread()
        {
#if YATM_WIN64
            if (m_handle != nullptr)
            {
                TerminateThread(m_handle, 0u);
            }
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_exit(nullptr);
#endif // YATM_WIN64
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        thread(const thread&) = delete;
        thread& operator=(const thread&) = delete;

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void create(uint32_t _index, size_t _stackSizeInBytes, ThreadEntryPoint _function, void* const _data)
        {
            m_index = _index;
            m_stackSizeInBytes = _stackSizeInBytes;

#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            m_thread = std::thread(_function, _data);
#elif YATM_WIN64
            m_handle = CreateThread(nullptr, m_stackSizeInBytes, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)_function, _data, 0, &m_threadId);
            YATM_ASSERT(m_handle != nullptr);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            m_threadId = _index;

            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
            pthread_attr_setstacksize (&attr, m_stackSizeInBytes);

            int32_t const errorCode = pthread_create(&m_thread, &attr, (void*(*)(void*))_function, _data);
            YATM_ASSERT(errorCode == 0);

            pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void join()
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            YATM_ASSERT(m_thread.joinable());
            m_thread.join();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            WaitForSingleObject(m_handle, INFINITE);
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_join(m_thread, nullptr);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get the thread worker index.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        uint32_t get_index() const { return m_index; }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get the OS thread index.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        size_t get_id() const
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            std::hash<std::thread::id> h;
            return h(m_thread.get_id());
#elif YATM_WIN64
    #if YATM_DEBUG
            DWORD h = GetThreadId(m_handle);
            YATM_ASSERT(h == m_threadId);
    #endif // YATM_DEBUG
            return (size_t)m_threadId;
#elif YATM_LINUX
            return m_threadId;
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

    private:
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
        std::thread m_thread;
#elif YATM_WIN64
        HANDLE      m_handle;
        DWORD       m_threadId;
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
        pthread_t m_thread;
        uint32_t  m_threadId;
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD

        size_t      m_stackSizeInBytes;
        uint32_t    m_index;
    };

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // A description for the scheduler to create the worker threads.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    struct scheduler_desc
    {
        uint32_t*   m_threadIds;                                                                        // Thread IDs, used to bind jobs to group of threads. Size must match m_numThreads and is initialised to defaults if not specified.
        uint32_t    m_numThreads;                                                                       // How many threads to use.
        uint32_t    m_stackSizeInBytes = YATM_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE;                                       // Stack size in bytes of each thread (unsupported in YATM_STD_THREAD).
        uint32_t    m_jobScratchBufferInBytes = YATM_DEFAULT_JOB_SCRATCH_BUFFER_SIZE;                   // Size in bytes of the internal scratch allocator. This is used to allocate jobs and job data.
        uint32_t    m_jobQueueReservation = YATM_DEFAULT_JOB_QUEUE_RESERVATION;                         // How many jobs to reserve in the job vector.
        uint32_t    m_pendingJobQueueReservation = YATM_DEFAULT_PENDING_JOB_QUEUE_RESERVATION;          // How many jobs to reserve in the pending job vector (jobs waiting to be kicked).
    };
    
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // A queue containing jobs to be processed.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class job_queue
    {
    public:
        job_queue()
        {
        }

        ~job_queue() 
        {
            m_queue.clear();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Lock this queue mutex.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void lock()
        {
            m_mutex.lock();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Attempt to lock this queue mutex.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        bool try_lock()
        {
            return m_mutex.try_lock();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Unlock this queue mutex.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void unlock()
        {
            m_mutex.unlock();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Notify the condition variable.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void notify()
        {
            m_cv.notify_one();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Reserve N jobs for this queue.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void reserve(size_t _size)
        {
            m_queue.reserve(_size);
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get the job at the specified index and remove it from the queue.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        job* const get_job(uint32_t _index)
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(_index < size());
            job* const j = m_queue[_index];
            m_queue.erase(m_queue.begin() + _index);
            return j;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get the job at the specified index and remove it from the queue. Similar to get_job, but this time the workerMask is checked against the desired worker index.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        job* const get_job(uint32_t _index, uint32_t _workerIndex)
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(_index < size());
            job* const j = m_queue[_index];

            if ( (j->m_workerMask & (1u << _workerIndex)) != 0)
            {
                m_queue.erase(m_queue.begin() + _index);
                return j;
            }

            return nullptr;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get the job at the specified index, but do not remove it from the queue.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        job* const peek_job(uint32_t _index) const
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(_index < size());
            return m_queue[_index];
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Push a job to the queue.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void push_back(job* const _job)
        {
            m_queue.push_back(_job);
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Perform work stealing from candidate queues.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void steal(job_queue* _candidates, uint32_t _size)
        {
#if YATM_ENABLE_WORK_STEALING
            // If the queue job count is 0, then we can attempt to steal from another queue.
            if (empty())
            {
                for (uint32_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
                {
                    job_queue& otherQueue = _candidates[i];

                    // Skip empty queues and same index
                    if ((&otherQueue == this) || (_candidates[i].empty()))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Find a compatible job for this queue.
                    otherQueue.lock();                  
                    job* stolen_job = nullptr;
                    uint32_t jobIndex = 0u;
                    if (!otherQueue.empty())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            stolen_job = otherQueue.get_job(jobIndex, i);
                        } while ((stolen_job == nullptr) && (jobIndex++ < otherQueue.size()));
                    }
                    otherQueue.unlock();

                    if (stolen_job != nullptr)
                    {
                        push_back(stolen_job);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
#endif // YATM_ENABLE_WORK_STEALING
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get the current size of the queue.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        size_t size() const
        {
            return m_queue.size();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Check if the queue is empty or not.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        bool empty() const
        {
            return size() == 0;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Wait until the condition is fulfilled.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        template<typename T>
        void wait(T _predicate)
        {
            m_cv.wait(m_mutex, _predicate);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<job*> m_queue;
        mutex m_mutex;
        condition_var m_cv;
    };

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // The task scheduler, used to dispatch tasks for consumption by the worker threads.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class scheduler
    {
    private:
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Used to pass in data when the workers are initialised.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        struct worker_thread_data
        {
            yatm::scheduler*    m_scheduler;
            uint32_t            m_id;
        };

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Worker internal
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        bool worker_internal(job* _job)
        {
            if (_job != nullptr)
            {
                // process job
                if (_job->m_function != nullptr)
                {
                    _job->m_function(_job->m_data);
                }

                // decrement the counter
                if (_job->m_counter != nullptr)
                {
                    _job->m_counter->decrement();
                }

                // Finish job, notifying parents recursively.
                finish_job(_job);
            }
            else
            {
                // No jobs, simply yield.
                yield();
            }

            return (_job != nullptr);
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get the next available compatible job and remove it from the queue.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        job* get_next_job(uint32_t _index)
        {
            job* current_job = nullptr;

            job_queue& queue = m_queues[_index];

            // Find the next job ready to be processed
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < queue.size(); ++i)
            {
                job* const j = queue.peek_job(i);
                // Can this job be processed by this worker thread?
                if (j->m_workerMask & (1u << _index))
                {
                    // This job has 1 remaining task, which means that all its dependencies have been processed.
                    // Pick this task, removing it from the job queue.
                    if (j->m_pendingJobs.is_equal(1u))
                    {
                        current_job = queue.get_job(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return current_job;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Worker entry point; pulls jobs from the global queue and processes them.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void worker_entry_point(uint32_t _index)
        {
            while (m_isRunning)
            {
                YATM_ASSERT(_index < m_queueCount);
                job_queue& queue = m_queues[_index];
                job* current_job = nullptr;
                {
                    queue.lock();

                    queue.steal(m_queues, m_queueCount);

                    // Wait for this thread to be woken up by the condition variable (there must be at least 1 job in the queue, or perhaps we want to simply stop)
                    queue.wait([this, &queue] { return !is_paused() && ((queue.size() > 0u) || !is_running()); });
                    current_job = get_next_job(_index);
                    queue.unlock();
                }
                worker_internal(current_job);
            }

#if YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_exit(nullptr);
#endif // YATM_USE_PTHREADS
        }

    public:
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        scheduler() :
            m_threads(nullptr), m_scratch(nullptr), m_currentWorkerMaskDepth(0u)
        {
            memset((void*)m_currentWorkerMasks, ~0u, sizeof(uint32_t) * YATM_MAX_WORKER_MASK_STACK_DEPTH);

#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            m_hwConcurency = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            SYSTEM_INFO info;
            ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
            GetSystemInfo(&info);
            m_hwConcurency = info.dwNumberOfProcessors;
#elif YATM_LINUX
            m_hwConcurency = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        virtual ~scheduler()
        {
            set_running(false);

            // wait for workers to finish
            join();

            // free thread data array
            delete[] m_threadData;
            m_threadData = nullptr;

            // free the thread array
            delete[] m_threads;
            m_threads = nullptr;

            // free the scratch allocator
            delete m_scratch;
            m_scratch = nullptr;

            delete[] m_queues;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        scheduler(const scheduler&) = delete;
        scheduler& operator=(const scheduler&) = delete;

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Initialise the scheduler.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void init(const scheduler_desc& _desc)
        {
            m_numThreads = std::max(1u, std::min<uint32_t>(_desc.m_numThreads, get_max_threads()));

            m_threadData = new worker_thread_data[m_numThreads];
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_numThreads; ++i)
            {
                m_threadData[i].m_scheduler = this;

                // Optinally copy custom worker ids (these will be used bitmasks when picking a worker for each job).
                m_threadData[i].m_id = (_desc.m_threadIds == nullptr) ? i : _desc.m_threadIds[i];
            }

            m_queueCount = m_numThreads;
            m_queues = new job_queue[m_queueCount];

#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            YATM_TTY("yatm is using std::thread, configurable stack size is not allowed");
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD

            m_stackSizeInBytes = align(_desc.m_stackSizeInBytes > 0 ? _desc.m_stackSizeInBytes : YATM_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE, 16u);

            m_threads = new thread[m_numThreads];
            m_scratch = new scratch( align(_desc.m_jobScratchBufferInBytes, 16u), 16u);

            // reserve some space in the global job queue
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_queueCount; ++i)
            {
                m_queues[i].reserve(_desc.m_jobQueueReservation);
            }

            // reserve some space in the currently pending job queue
            m_pendingJobsToAdd.reserve(_desc.m_pendingJobQueueReservation);

            // enable the scheduler and let its workers run
            set_running(true);
            set_paused(false);

            // Create N worker threads and kick them off.
            // Each worker will process the next available job item from the global queue, resolve its dependencies and carry on until no jobs are left.
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_numThreads; ++i)
            {
                auto func = [](void* data) -> void
                {
                    worker_thread_data* d = reinterpret_cast<worker_thread_data*>(data);
                    d->m_scheduler->worker_entry_point(d->m_id);
                };

                m_threads[i].create(i, m_stackSizeInBytes, func, &m_threadData[i]);
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Resets the internal scratch allocator.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void reset()
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(m_scratch != nullptr);
            m_scratch->reset();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Push a new worker mask depth, subsequent job allocations will be set to run on the specified workers.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void push_worker_mask(uint32_t _workerMask)
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(m_currentWorkerMaskDepth < YATM_MAX_WORKER_MASK_STACK_DEPTH);
            m_currentWorkerMasks[++m_currentWorkerMaskDepth] = _workerMask;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Pop worker mask depth.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void pop_worker_mask()
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(m_currentWorkerMaskDepth > 0);
            --m_currentWorkerMaskDepth;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Create a job from the scheduler scratch allocator.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        template<typename Function>
        job* const create_job(const Function& _function, void* const _data, counter* _counter)
        {
            job* const j = allocate<job>();

            j->m_function = _function;
            j->m_data = _data;
            j->m_parent = nullptr;
            j->m_counter = _counter;
            j->m_workerMask = m_currentWorkerMasks[m_currentWorkerMaskDepth];

            // Initialise the job with 1 pending job (itself).
            // Adding dependencies increments the pending counter, resolving dependencies decrements it.
            j->m_pendingJobs.increment();

            // Register this newly created job; all jobs are automatically added when the scheduler kicks-off the tasks.
            scoped_lock<mutex> lock(&m_pendingJobsMutex);
            m_pendingJobsToAdd.push_back(j);

            return j;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Create a group from the scheduler scratch allocator. A group is simply a job without any work to be done, used as a dependency in other
        // jobs to create a hierarchy of tasks.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        job* const create_group(job* const _parent = nullptr)
        {
            job* const group = create_job(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

            // If a parent is specified, setup this dependency
            if (_parent != nullptr)
            {
                depend(_parent, group);
            }

            return group;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Allocate a temporary array using the scheduler scratch allocator.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        template<typename T>
        T* allocate(size_t _count, size_t _alignment = 16u)
        {
            uint8_t* mem = m_scratch->alloc(sizeof(T) * _count, _alignment);
            return new(mem) T[_count];
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Allocate a temporary object using the scheduler scratch allocator.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        template<typename T>
        T* allocate(size_t _alignment = 16u)
        {
            uint8_t* mem = m_scratch->alloc(sizeof(T), _alignment);

            T* obj = new(mem) T();
            return obj;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Adds a job dependency on the specified job.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void depend(job* const _target, job* const _dependency)
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(_dependency->m_parent == nullptr);

            _dependency->m_parent = _target;
            _target->m_pendingJobs.increment();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Creates a parallel for loop for the specified collection, launching _function per iteration.
        // Blocks until all are complete.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        template<typename Iterator, typename Function>
        void parallel_for(const Iterator& _begin, const Iterator& _end, const Function& _function)
        {
            const size_t n = std::distance(_begin, _end);
            if (n > 0)
            {
                // When there is only 1 job, don't pass it through the scheduler.
                if (n == 1)
                {
                    _function(&(*(_begin)));
                }
                else
                {
                    counter jobs_done;
                    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                    {
                        job* j = create_job(_function, &(*(_begin + i)), &jobs_done);
                    }

                    kick();
                    wait(&jobs_done);
                }
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Signal the worker threads that work has been added.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void kick()
        {
            // Add the pending jobs to the global job queue and notify the worker threads that work has been added.
            {
                scoped_lock<mutex> lock(&m_pendingJobsMutex);

#if YATM_DEBUG
                verify_job_graph();
#endif // YATM_DEBUG

                for (auto& job : m_pendingJobsToAdd)
                {
                    // Verify that the job and its data is allocated from scratch buffer.
                    YATM_ASSERT(m_scratch->is_from(job));

                    add_job(job);
                }
                m_pendingJobsToAdd.clear();
            }

            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_queueCount; ++i)
            {
                m_queues[i].notify();
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Try to process the job on a compatible worker thread.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void process_single_job()
        {           
            uint32_t const index = get_random_queue_index();

            // Find compatible job to process
            if (m_queues[index].try_lock())
            {
                job* current_job = get_next_job(index);
                m_queues[index].unlock();

                worker_internal(current_job);
            }
            yield();                        
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Wait for a single job to complete. In the meantime, try to process one pending job.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void wait(job* const _job)
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(_job != nullptr);
            while (!_job->m_pendingJobs.is_done())
            {
                process_single_job();
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Wait for a counter to reach 0. In the meantime, try to process one pending job.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void wait(counter* const _counter)
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(_counter != nullptr);
            while (!_counter->is_done())
            {
                // Process jobs while waiting
                process_single_job();
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Yield the current thread and allow others to execute.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void yield()
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            std::this_thread::yield();
#elif YATM_WIN64
            SwitchToThread();
#elif YATM_USE_PTHREADS
            pthread_yield();
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Return the maximum number of worker threads.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        uint32_t get_max_threads() const { return m_hwConcurency; }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Check if the scheduler is running worker functions.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        bool is_running() const { return m_isRunning; }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Stop the scheduler from processing, effectively shutting it down.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void set_running(bool _running)
        {
            m_isRunning = _running;
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_queueCount; ++i)
            {
                m_queues[i].notify();
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Check if the scheduler is paused.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        bool is_paused() const { return m_isPaused; }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Set the paused status of the scheduler. Worker threads will not process anything until status is resumed.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void set_paused(bool _paused)
        {
            m_isPaused = _paused;
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_queueCount; ++i)
            {
                m_queues[i].notify();
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Allow the current thread to sleep for specified duration in ms.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void sleep(uint32_t ms)
        {
#if YATM_STD_THREAD
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
#elif YATM_WIN64
            Sleep(ms);
#elif YATM_LINUX
            usleep(ms * 1000);
#endif // YATM_STD_THREAD
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Wait for all the worker threads to stop executing, block the main thread.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void join()
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(m_threads != nullptr);
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_numThreads; ++i)
            {
                m_threads[i].join();
            }
        }

    private:        
        mutex                   m_pendingJobsMutex;
        size_t                  m_stackSizeInBytes;
        uint32_t                m_hwConcurency;
        uint32_t                m_currentWorkerMasks[YATM_MAX_WORKER_MASK_STACK_DEPTH];
        uint32_t                m_currentWorkerMaskDepth;
        uint32_t                m_numThreads;
        uint32_t                m_queueCount;
        worker_thread_data*     m_threadData;
        bool                    m_isRunning;
        bool                    m_isPaused;     
        thread*                 m_threads;
        job_queue*              m_queues;
        std::vector<job*>       m_pendingJobsToAdd;

#if YATM_DEBUG
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Verify the job graph.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void verify_job_graph()
        {

        }
#endif // YATM_DEBUG

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get a random queue index
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        uint32_t get_random_queue_index() const
        {
            uint32_t const index = std::rand() % m_queueCount;
            return index;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get a random queue.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        job_queue& get_random_queue()
        {
            uint32_t const index = get_random_queue_index();
            return m_queues[index];
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Adds a single job item to the scheduler. Assumes the caller ensures thread safety.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void add_job(job* const _job)
        {
            YATM_ASSERT(_job != nullptr);

            if (_job->m_counter != nullptr)
            {
                _job->m_counter->increment();
            }

            get_random_queue().push_back(_job);
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Mark this job as finished by decrementing the pendingJobs counter and inform its parents recursively.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        void finish_job(job* const _job)
        {
            if (_job != nullptr)
            {
                const uint32_t p = _job->m_pendingJobs.decrement();
                // If this job has finished, inform its parent.
                if (p == 0)
                {
                    finish_job(_job->m_parent);
                }
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // A scratch allocator to handle data and job allocations.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        class scratch
        {
        public:
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            scratch(size_t _sizeInBytes, size_t _alignment)
                : m_sizeInBytes(_sizeInBytes), m_alignment(_alignment), m_begin(nullptr), m_end(nullptr), m_current(nullptr)

            {
                YATM_ASSERT(is_pow2(m_alignment));

                m_begin = (uint8_t*)aligned_alloc(m_sizeInBytes, m_alignment);
                YATM_ASSERT(m_begin != nullptr);

                m_end = m_begin + m_sizeInBytes;
                m_current = m_begin;
            }

            scratch(const scratch&) = delete;
            scratch& operator=(const scratch&) = delete;

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ~scratch()
            {
                if (m_begin != nullptr)
                {
                    aligned_free(m_begin);
                }
            }

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Reset the scratch current pointer.
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            void reset()
            {
                m_current = m_begin;
            }

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Return the current (aligned) address of the scratch allocator and increment the pointer.
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            uint8_t* alloc(size_t _size, size_t _align)
            {
                YATM_ASSERT(is_pow2(_align));

                scoped_lock<mutex> lock(&m_mutex);
                m_current = align_ptr(m_current, _align);

                YATM_ASSERT(m_current + _size < m_end);
                uint8_t* mem = m_current;
                m_current += _size;

#if YATM_DEBUG
                memset(mem, 0xbabababa, _size);
#endif // YATM_DEBUG

                return mem;
            }

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Checks if the input pointer is within the scratch allocator's memory boundaries.
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            bool is_from(void* _ptr)
            {
                const uint8_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(_ptr);
                return (ptr >= m_begin && ptr < m_end);
            }

        private:
            mutex       m_mutex;
            uint8_t*    m_begin;
            uint8_t*    m_end;
            uint8_t*    m_current;
            size_t      m_sizeInBytes;
            size_t      m_alignment;

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Checks if the input is a power of two.
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            bool is_pow2(size_t _n)
            {
                return (_n & (_n - 1)) == 0;
            }

        public:
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // A portable aligned allocation mechanism.
            //
            // Thanks to: https://gist.github.com/dblalock/255e76195676daa5cbc57b9b36d1c99a
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            void* aligned_alloc(size_t _size, size_t _alignment)
            {
                YATM_ASSERT(_alignment < UINT8_MAX);

                // over-allocate using malloc and adjust pointer by the offset needed to align the memory to specified alignment
                const size_t request_size = _size + _alignment;
                uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*)malloc(request_size);

                // figure out how much we should offset our allocation by
                const size_t remainder = ((size_t)buf) % _alignment;
                const size_t offset = _alignment - remainder;
                uint8_t* ret = buf + (uint8_t)offset;

                // store how many extra bytes we allocated in the byte just before the pointer we return
                *(uint8_t*)(ret - 1) = (uint8_t)offset;

                return ret;
            }

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            void aligned_free(const void* const aligned_ptr)
            {
                // find the base allocation by extracting the stored aligned offset and free it
                uint32_t offset = *(((uint8_t*)aligned_ptr) - 1);
                free(((uint8_t*)aligned_ptr) - offset);
            }
        } *m_scratch;
    };
}
```

Example usage #1:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sample_parallel_for(yatm::scheduler& sch)
{
    while (true)
    {
        sch.reset();
        {
            yatm::scoped_profiler profiler;

            // Setup some data for processing
            const uint32_t dataLength = 100u;
            uint32_t uints[dataLength];

            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < std::size(uints); i++)
            {
                uints[i] = i;
            }

            sch.push_worker_mask(~0u);

            // Launch them in parallel:
            // Creates as many tasks as the length of specified data, kicks them and blocks the caller thread until they are finished.
            sch.parallel_for((uint32_t*)uints, (uint32_t*)uints + dataLength, [](void* const param)
            {
                uint32_t idx = *(uint32_t*)param;

                // do some intensive work
                const auto result = yatm::work(idx);

                char t[64];
                sprintf_fn(t, "Result for data %u: %ld\n", idx, result);
                std::cout << t;
            });
            sch.pop_worker_mask();
        }
        sch.sleep(2000);
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    yatm::scheduler sch;
    yatm::init(sch);
    sample_parallel_for(sch);
    return 0;
}
```

Example usage #2

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sample_job_dependencies(yatm::scheduler& sch)
{
    static uint32_t c_numChildTasks = 30;   // group child tasks.
    static uint32_t c_numIterations = ~0u;  // -1 for infinite iterations

    // Run for N iterations
    uint32_t iter = 0u;
    float averageMs = 0.0f;
    while ((iter++ < c_numIterations) || (c_numIterations == ~0u))
    {
        sch.reset();

        {
            yatm::scoped_profiler profiler;

            yatm::counter counter;

            // Prepare the job graph
            // This looks like this:
            /*
            [parent]
            /        \
            /         \
            [group0]          [group1]
            /                       \
            /                        \
            [group0_job]                  [group1_job]
            |                           |
            |                           |
            |---> child_0               |---> child_0
            | ....                      | ...
            |---> child_n               |---> child_n

            Expected result is the children of each [groupN_job] task to be executed first. When all of the dependencies of each [groupN_job] are resolved,
            [groupN_job] will be executed. Once that happens, [groupN] is executed (being a simple group without a job function, it does nothing, simply used for grouping).
            Once both [group0] and [group1] are finished, [parent] executes and the tasks are complete.

            After [parent] is finished, sch.wait(parent) will unblock and main thread execution will continue.
            An alternative way to wait for the tasks to finish is by using the yatm::counter object. This is atomically incremented when jobs that reference it are added to
            the scheduler and decremented when jobs are finished. When the counter reached 0, it's assumed to be finished and sch.wait(&counter) will unblock the main thread.

            */
            // Parent task depends on everything else below. This will be executed last.
            yatm::job* const parent = sch.create_job
            (
                [](void* const data)
                {
                    std::cout << "Parent, this should execute after all the groups have finished.\n";
                }
                ,
                nullptr,
                &counter
                );

            // allocate data for the child tasks; they simply hold the loop index, but more complex structures can be used.
            uint32_t* const data = sch.allocate<uint32_t>(c_numChildTasks, 16u);

            // Make a few groups to put the children jobs under. Group0 will depend on children [0, N/2-1] and group1 will depend on children [N/2, N]
            // Group0_job and group1_job will execute once their respective children have finished executing.
            yatm::job* const group0 = sch.create_group(parent);
            yatm::job* const group0_job = sch.create_job([](void* const data) { std::cout << "Group 0 job, executing after all child 0 are finished.\n"; }, nullptr, &counter);
            sch.depend(group0, group0_job);

            yatm::job* const group1 = sch.create_group(parent);
            yatm::job* const group1_job = sch.create_job([](void* const data) { std::cout << "Group 1 job, executing after all child 1 are finished.\n"; }, nullptr, &counter);
            sch.depend(group1, group1_job);

            // Create child tasks
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < c_numChildTasks; ++i)
            {
                data[i] = i;
                yatm::job* const child = sch.create_job
                (
                    [](void* const data)
                    {
                        uint32_t idx = *(uint32_t*)data;

                        // do some intensive work
                        uint64_t result = yatm::work(idx);

                        const uint32_t group = idx < c_numChildTasks / 2 ? 0 : 1;
                        char str[512];
                        sprintf_fn(str, "Child %u (group %u). Children of groups should execute first, result: %ld.\n", idx, group, result);

                        std::cout << str;
                    },
                    &data[i],
                    &counter
                    );

                if (i < c_numChildTasks / 2)
                {
                    sch.depend(group0_job, child);
                }
                else
                {
                    sch.depend(group1_job, child);
                }
            }

            // Add the created tasks and signal the workers to begin processing them
            sch.kick();
            // Wait for finished tasks. Here we wait on the parent, as this will guarantee that all of the tasks will be complete.
            sch.wait(parent);

            // Or:
            // sch.wait(&counter);
            //
            // The counter can also be only added on the parent (instead of all the tasks, as done above).
            // Since the parent depends on all the other tasks, having the counter only on that single job is enough.
        }
        // Pause for a bit, resume after 1000ms
        sch.set_paused(true);
        sch.sleep(1000);
        sch.set_paused(false);
    }
    sch.set_running(false);
    sch.sleep(2000);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    yatm::scheduler sch;
    yatm::init(sch);
    sample_job_dependencies(sch);
    return 0;
}
```